# python, how to count down from 10 by using the while operator

Tags: python

I want to make a program that counts down from 10 by using the operator while.

This is what I have so far but it would not do what I want.

```
i = 10    
while i < 10:         
    print(i)   
    i = i-1
```

This doesn't work and I'd like to know why!

Comment: Well if you intialise `i=10` why do you expect `i<10`?

Comment: Why do you think this would ever go inside the while block? If you really think it should, I would suggest you start from some basic tutorial.

Comment: And, if it ever got inside the `while` loop, *why would it ever stop?!*

Answer (score 0):

You exit the loop as soon as i is less than 10. 9 is less than 10 so you leave the loop in the first run. What you need is:

```
i = 10    
while i > 0:         
    print(i)   
    i = i-1
```

In this case you stay in the loop as long as `i` is greater than zero.

Comment: @VigneshKalai Execute `10 < 10` in your Python interpreter. What do you see? `True` or `False`?

Comment: @Alex.S False sorry my mistake

Comment: @jonrsharpe my mistake

Answer (score 0):

`i < 10` means "i is less than 10"
`i > 10` means "i is greater than 10"

The symbol is a bit like an arrow. It always points towards the smaller item. This is slightly different if you are checking for a condition.

`if i < 10` is saying "if i is less than 10"
`while i > 10` is saying, "while i is greater than 10"

So this is what you need:

```
i = 10
while i > 0: # while i is greater than zero
    print(i)
    i = i - 1 # i will eventually be less than zero, meaning the
              # condition for the loop will return false and stop the loop
```

This will print i from 10 to 0

Comment: Do we need duplicate answers for this question?

Comment: I thought it was worth a little more explanation of the symbols involved

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown you the way how to do it with `while`. My question is why do you want to do it by using `while`. If there are no constrains, I would suggest you to look for `range`:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-range

You could implement your counting like this:

```
for i in range(11):
    print(i)

#output
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

To count down just reverse the range function:

```
for i in reversed(range(11)):
    print(i)

#output
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

I hope this alternative can help you.